# Python built in function - Input

Tags: python

I run this code as a .py file which will bring up a command prompt from the built in Python function `input`. (not alot of wisdom here...) If I enter `diagnose`, hit enter only `vav2_12` will work to print `booya` all others on the list will print `not working`

Would anyone know why?

```
#list of addresses of controllers
# format : key = name, v = (address, device_identifier) tuple
vavs = {'vav1_1': ('1701:1'),
        'vav1_2': ('1701:2'),
        'vav1_3': ('1701:3'),
        'vav1_4': ('1701:4'),
        'vav1_5': ('1701:5'),
        'vav1_6': ('1701:6'),
        'vav1_7': ('1701:7'),
        'vav1_8': ('1701:8'),
        'vav1_9': ('1701:9'),
        'vav1_10': ('1701:10'),
        'vav1_11': ('1701:11'),
        'vav1_12': ('1701:12'),
        'vav2_1': ('1701:13'),
        'vav2_2': ('1701:14'),
        'vav2_3': ('1701:15'),
        'vav2_4': ('1701:16'),
        'vav2_5': ('1701:17'),
        'vav2_6': ('1701:18'),
        'vav2_7': ('1701:19'),
        'vav2_8': ('1701:20'),
        'vav2_9': ('1701:21'),
        'vav2_10': ('1701:22'),
        'vav2_11': ('1701:23'),
        'vav2_12': ('1701:24'),
       }


#dict(TUPLE)[key]
d = dict(vavs)

while True:

    answer = input('Available actions: check_temps or diagnose?')

    if answer == 'check_temps':
        print('Checking Some Temps ...')


    if answer == 'diagnose':

        #print list of controller addresses
        for vav in vavs.items():
            print(vav[0])

        diagAnswer = input('Which VAV to check?')

        if vav[0] == diagAnswer:
            print('Booya')

        else:
            print('Not working')

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: I assume you want to move the ```vav[0] == diagAnswer```into the ```for vava in vavas.items()``` loop.

Comment: Also, you are seemingly trying to find the key in the dict. You can use the ```.get()``` method to check if a value exists or simply use the ```in``` keyword.

Comment: FYI it's conventional in Python to use names `like_this` not `likeThis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because vav value is the last item from the vavs after iteration.

I belive that solution for you wolud be this:

```
if diagAnswer in vavs.keys():
    print('Booya')
else:
    print('Not working')
```